# Mongodb query for counting the distinct value across all documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Sample Docs :**

```
{"id": "1",  "movie_data": "enemies": ["a", "b", "v-glaive", "t-midnight", "t-obsidian", "u-klaue"], "groups": ["avengers"], "movies": []}
{"id": "2",  "movie_data": "enemies": ["a", "d"], "groups": ["avengers"], "movies": []}
{"id": "3",  "movie_data": "enemies": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], "groups": ["avengers"], "movies": []}
```

Here I need Group - Avenger and enemy count as distinct values of enemies across all collections.

```
Avenger - enemy count - 9
```

Comment: You could use distinct. Something like `db.collection.distinct("movie_data.enemies", {"movie_data.groups":"avengers"}).length;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it done using MongoDB's [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   /** unwind creates multiple docs for each value in array */
  {
    $unwind: "$movie_data.groups"
  },
  /** Pick docs where we've groups as 'avengers' */
  {
    $match: {
      "movie_data.groups": "avengers"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$movie_data.enemies"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$movie_data.groups",
      uniqueEmemies: {
        $addToSet: "$movie_data.enemies" /** Adds unique value to array */
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id : 0,
      group: "$_id",
      uniqueEnemyCount: {
        $size: "$uniqueEmemies"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LpAuooEUvV1)